# Index and match with concatenated values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to index and match values that are in 2 separate columns.  If it was an Excel formula it would look like....

```
 =INDEX('Critical Times'!D:D,MATCH(CONCATENATE(B7,C7),'Critical Times'!G:G,0))
```

I'm struggling to carry this out in VBA though.  I've tried the code below but it's not working.  What is happening here is it goes down each line in a column and writes a value for a start date and end date until it hits a blank row.

I have tried a slightly different version where it only matches cell C7 against another column and it works fine.  It's only when I want to join the values in B7 and C7 that it stops working.  Excuse me if the code is a bit messy, still learning!

```
Dim r As Range


Worksheets("Overview").Activate


Set r = Range("B7") & Range("c7")

Do While r.Value <> ""


Dim datestr As Long
Dim dateend As Long
datestr = WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Critical Times").Range("D:D"),     WorksheetFunction.Match(r.Value, Worksheets("Critical Times").Range("G:G"), 0), 0)
dateend = WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Critical Times").Range("E:E"),     WorksheetFunction.Match(r.Value, Worksheets("Critical Times").Range("G:G"), 0), 0)


Dim MatchFormula As Long
Dim ColumnMatch As Long
Dim MatchFormula2 As Long
Dim ColumnMatch2 As Long



If datestr <> 0 Then
MatchFormula = WorksheetFunction.Match(r.Value, Range("C:C"), 0)
ColumnMatch = WorksheetFunction.Match(datestr, Range("4:4"), 0)
Range(Col_Letter(ColumnMatch) & MatchFormula).Value = "A"

MatchFormula2 = WorksheetFunction.Match(r.Value, Range("C:C"), 0)
ColumnMatch2 = WorksheetFunction.Match(dateend, Range("4:4"), 0)
Range(Col_Letter(ColumnMatch2) & MatchFormula2).Value = "A"
End If

    Set r = r.Offset(1)
  Loop
```

Comment: One option would be to set a cell in `G` column using `.Find`, then `.Offset` to get the `D` column value. Furthermore, for future reference, concatenating multiple values in a `MATCH` isn't the best way. Imagine values like `11` and `11` concatenated....

Comment: I agree with the concatenation point, I wouldn't do that normally in forumulas in Excel but would index and match with multiple criteria.  I felt that was beyond me in vba though to be honest so thought joining the values together was easier.

Comment: So if concatenating is bad practice in worksheet formulas, it's also bad practice in VBA. So would you not rather loop through a range and check multiple values? Would you appreciate a simplified example?

Comment: Please, I would appreciate it

Comment: =INDEX('Critical Times'!D:D,MATCH(1,INDEX(('Critical Times'!A:A=B7)*('Critical Times'!B:B=C7),0,1),0))
That's how I would do it if it was an Excel formula normally.

Comment: If you combine @KeithWilliams solution with table formatting it will be much less computationally demanding as well. The secret to his formula is to make sure to hit `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER`

Comment: @MarkS. doing so through VBA does not require CSE like formulas. Excel picks up whether or not this is needed, and silently applies the array.

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine this sample data:

```
| Tests | Vals | Return |
|-------|------|--------|
| Test1 | Val1 | Ret1 |
| Test1 | Val2 | Ret2 |
| Test1 | Val3 | Ret3 |
| Test1 | Val4 | Ret4 |
| Test1 | Val5 | Ret5 |
| Test2 | Val1 | Ret6 |
| Test2 | Val2 | Ret7 |
| Test2 | Val3 | Ret8 |
| Test2 | Val4 | Ret9 |
| Test2 | Val5 | Ret10 |
| Test3 | Val1 | Ret11 |
| Test3 | Val2 | Ret12 |
| Test3 | Val3 | Ret13 |
| Test3 | Val4 | Ret14 |
| Test3 | Val5 | Ret15 |
```

To return a certain value based on multiple criteria (col A and col B in this case) we could use some iteration over a range like so:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
Dim var1 As String, var2 As String, fa As String

var1 = "Test2"
var2 = "Val4"

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each cl In rng
        If cl.Value = var1 And cl.Offset(0, 1).Offset = var2 Then
            Debug.Print cl.Offset(0, 2).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cl
End With

End Sub
```

If your datarange is huge, it might be beneficial to look into [`.FindNext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext) to prevent long iteration and processing times.

---

If you are certain these values excist you could also use the [`.Evaluate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) function to emulate a worksheetfunction and return it's result. In that case `.Evaluate` will recognize you meant to use an array formula so no need for the second `INDEX`. Example:

```
Sub Test2()

Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
Dim var1 As String, var2 As String, fa As String

var1 = "Test2"
var2 = "Val4"

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Debug.Print .Evaluate("=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,(A:A=""" & var1 & """)*(B:B=""" & var2 & """),0))")
End With

End Sub
```

To improve process time, you can define ranges and implement these in the evaluation formula too.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do that.  In the original code, datestr and dateend = the index and match formulas I was trying to use.  In the second example, how would I define each of them?  Sorry if that's a stupid question, trying to pick my way through this still

Comment: @KeithWilliams, If it's long variable you can dim them as long, furthermore you can remove one of the triple quotes since we don't need text values no longer but numeric values. It would look like: `Dim var1 As Long, var2 As Long` and also `.Evaluate("=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,(A:A="" & var1 & "")*(B:B="" & var2 & ""),0))")`

Comment: Sorry no, but it's more to do with my lack of understanding!

Comment: @KeithWilliams, maybe it's me not understanding your requirement. Do you want to refer to two particular cells instead of variables?